# Fetch user id and profile picture - mysql

Tags: mysql, database, facebook, image, userid

I'm a beginner when it comes to php/scripting - or "websiting" in general. 
What I really would like to do, is to fetch a users profile picture and user id, when the person clicks on the "Login with facebook" button. I then want to be able to div this out on my page. Is it a way to do this via mysql? When the person clicks login/allow, their picture and user name will be stored in my database and then displayed? 
To my understanding, I have to go via the FB.api?

Thank you who answers :).

Answer (score 0):

1. Once user authorize your app with basic permissions, you'll get a access token.More about authentication can be [found here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)
2. Once you get the access token, you need to send a get request to https://graph.facebook.com/me with the access_token you received in step 1
3. It will contain JSON string that will contain userid and link to profile picture, you can save that to your mysql database

More about graph api can be [found here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)